# MySQL sorting twice on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

My database is like

```
id|service_id
1 | 8
2 | 3
3 | 4
4 | 1
5 | 3
6 | 2
7 | 1
```

i want to sort it like rows with same `service_id` came together but randomly. like

```
id|service_id
1 | 8
4 | 1
7 | 1
2 | 3
5 | 3
6 | 2
3 | 4
```

means first all rows sort via `service_id` then again sort via random `service_id`. I have tried `SELECT * from sample_table order by service_id DESC` and tried `ASC` too but it only do sort via `DESC` or `ASC`. I have tried `order by rand(service_id)` too but it is also showing some fixed sorting.

Comment: What do you mean by ```order by rand(service_id)``` shows fixed sorting?

Comment: no this also doesnt fixed problem.

Comment: @SandeshGupta was asking you something not answering your question, perhaps you should actually read what he wrote instead of just sending a generic this is not my answer

Comment: @lad2025 do you not understand what i said above? Im pretty sure *i* understand the question. Maybe you should read my statement from above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select t.*
from your_table t
join 
(
  select service_id, rand() as r
  from your_table 
  group by service_id
) tmp on t.service_id = tmp.service_id
order by tmp.r;
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/709356/8)

Basically this makes a random substitute for the `service_id` and orders by that